# How to iterate and append characters of an array by push

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var charArray=[a,b,c]
```

I want to have a new array as following:

```
var charArrayNew=[a, ab, abc]
```

Please suggest how to get the result of `charArrayNew` in ES6 Javascript.

Comment: Hint: use the `substr()` method.

Comment: let charArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let charArrayNew = [];

charArray.forEach((item,index)=>{
        charArrayNew.push(charArray.slice(0, index+1).join(''))
    })


console.log(charArrayNew)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```js
const charArray=['a','b','c'];
const answer = charArray.map((_,i,ar)=>ar.slice(0,i+1).join(""));
console.log(answer);

// or, alternatively:
fn=(ar,res=[])=>(
 ar.reduce((a,c)=>(res.push(a+=c),a),""),res );
 
console.log(fn(charArray))
```